# set up Firebasefirestore Xamarin.android error

Tags: c#, android, firebase, visual-studio, xamarin

recently i've been trying to set up a connection to my Firestore database. I followed the instructions given in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mneY6H0zMNE&t=704s&ab_channel=Ufinix) video only that there is a runtime exception when it tries to get the data base via `GetDatabase()`

```
 public static FirebaseFirestore GetDatabase()
        {
            FirebaseFirestore database;

            var app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context);
            if (app == null)
            {
                var options = new Firebase.FirebaseOptions.Builder()
               .SetProjectId("fulcrum-7c537")
               .SetApplicationId("fulcrum-7c537")
               .SetApiKey("AIzaSyA8lo7k0EFPNR32-g4xdBnMkQnycn_v4G8")
               .SetDatabaseUrl("https://fulcrum-7c537.firebaseio.com")
               .SetStorageBucket("fulcrum-7c537.appspot.com")
               .Build();

                app = Firebase.FirebaseApp.InitializeApp(Application.Context , options);
            }

            database = FirebaseFirestore.GetInstance(app);
            return database;
        }
```

The Exception :

```
Java.Lang.NoClassDefFoundError
Message=Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/common/io/BaseEncoding;
```

I have been trying for a while to find out why it happens but found nothing. May someone has a solution?
Thanks!

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Comment: Hey, sorry, fixed it

Comment: if I google that error message I get a lot of hits - what have you tried so far?

Comment: i have tried to work with another Nugget called Firebase but I understood that it is useful for realtime database and not for firestore database

Comment: Have you do any change with the code in video? I followed the sample on video and do not reproduce your issue. I would check again and feedback ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue. I downloaded the code provided by Ufinix (the creator of the video). I downgraded the Xamarin.Google.Guava current version 28.2.0 I used, to the 27.1.0.1 version he used in his example. And finally, it worked.